# Iterating rasters in ModelBuilder - wildcard does not seem to work?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, iterator, wildcard, precondition

I've got some problem with the model below.

[image]

I want to extract rasters from sde geodatabase, use one parameter from Copy Raster, and then export it to specified folder with preserved names as an output. I need to use all operation, like on the printscreen, because this model do 'almost' what i want (maybe Iterate can be replaced by some script?).

My problem is that I want to limit my inputs - in sde.gdb I have 35000 rasters, and each of it has almost 2GB size (I know how much I can do at once after 24h, and for the whole set it will take ~ 6 days, but it would be nice to be able to leave my computer to do this only after working hours).

I want to be able to choose range (I've got unique values like ObjectID and Name which could be used to obtain it) but I don't know what I do wrong.

[image: table]

In Iterate Rasters I use Wildcard parameter but seems it doesn't work. Already know that for sde I need to use "%" and "_" signs instead of "*" and "?". In wildcard space I just simply wrote " OBJECTID Like '12___' " (for e.g. to be able to choose only raster with IDs from 12000 to 12999)

Anyone can me explain what I do wrong? Or maybe I need to set something more in model (like preconditions).

### Maybe I do mistake and there should be some sql expression within wildcard or I need use some more tools?

Maybe I've got something wrong with my data so I uploaded small sample (4 small rasters and saved model ~5MB) [my sample data](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=00537132164134712724). Idea will be the same for this sample and whole .sde (except changing specific signs for .sde instead of personal geodatabase I suppose)

No matter what I do, it seems like the whole process skip wildacard function and start everytime from the first ID.

Don't know if it's matter but I use ArcGIS 10.0

Answer (score 1):

objectid is an integer field, so you can't compare it with a string. In your case, I suggest that you first create a table view with a whereclause like `"OBJECTID" >= 12000 AND "OBJECTID" < 13000` . You could also convert the objectId to string, but this is not the best solution in my humble opinion;

Comment: Thx for response
I'm not sure what you mean by "create a table view" - use "make table view" from data managemnet tool (in this model or a submodel and how to link it)? Or to use expression you've mentioned in wildcard empty space? (Maybe it's silly question but I'm starting with some more advanced options within ArcMap)